# Counter for one unique expression for every row in Power Query

Tags: excel, counter, powerquery

I try to get a counter for an unique expression in my table. My table looks something like this:

[Starting format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SRJN.png)

so everytime the expression "Date" appears in the voteOptionText column the counter should increase by one, so that I'm able to distinguish between the diffrent persons who gave the answers, because I know every new set of data begins with the date expression. So it should look like this:

[Desired counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ6wz.png)

So the counter should only count the word "date" and not other expressions.

I need this counter to pivot the table afterwards and to distinguish multiple answers. So the next step would be to pivot the index column. Do you have any idea how to get this counter? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You may use following approach:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    group = Table.Group(Source, {"voteOptionText"}, {"temp", each _}, 0, (a,b)=>Number.From(b[voteOptionText]="Date")),
    i = Table.AddIndexColumn(group, "i", 1),
    del = Table.RemoveColumns(i,"voteOptionText"),
    final = Table.ExpandTableColumn(del, "temp", {"voteOptionText", "voteAnswer"})
in
    final
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to have a sequential number in your "Counter" column. You just need to have the same number for each group.  You can then `Group` by the Counter column.

So I would

- Add an index column
- Add a custom column whereby if the contents of `voteOptionText` is `Date` then copy the Index number, else null
- Fill down

eg

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Add Counter Column    
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Counter", 
        each if [voteOptionText] = "Date" then [Index] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Counter"}),

//Remove Index column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

***Note:** You mentioned you wanted to Pivot the results. Since you have multiple rows with the same content/label, you will need to do some further processing before you can create the Pivot Table*